# Zabbix - Having difficulty to aggregate data generated by using UserParameter

Tags: zabbix

I have managed to use UserParameter in **zabbix_agentd.conf** file to create several items and start to collecting data and generating graph.

**sjdc-lws-a** and **sjdc-lws-b** are the zabbix agents that I have the UserParameter commands added
and RTDA.SJDC.Cores and RTDA.CHN.Cores are the keys of the items I have defined.

on sjdc-lws-a => **UserParameter=RTDA.SJDC.Cores,/tmp/sys_test.py | cut -f1 -d" "**

on sjdc-lws-b => **UserParameter=RTDA.CHN.Cores,/tmp/sys_test.py | cut -f2 -d" "**

But when I tried to create a new item to aggregate these two UserParameter generated items, It failed to create the new item.

This is the key I entered to generate the new item on Zabbix Server

**last("sjdc-lws-a:RTDA.SJDC.Cores")+last("sjdc-lws-b:RTDA.CHN.Cores")**

When I clicked **Add**, I got the following error message

**Invalid key** "last("sjdc-lws-a:RTDA.SJDC.Cores")+last("sjdc-lws-b:RTDA.CHN.Cores")" for item "RTDA.Total.Cores" on "Zabbix server": incorrect syntax near "("sjdc-lws-a:RTDA.SJDC.Cores")+last("sjdc-lws ...". [items.php:564 → CFrontendApiWrapper->create() → CApiWrapper->__call() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callMethod() → CApiWrapper->callMethod() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callClientMethod() → CLocalApiClient->callMethod() → call_user_func_array() → CItem->create() → CItemGeneral->checkInput() → CApiService::exception() in include/classes/api/services/CItemGeneral.php:391]

**RTDA.Total.Cores** is the new item that I try to create.

Can anyone help me to find out why those keys are considered invalid?

The defined items (with these keys) do work and collecting data

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that the visible host name that you are trying to use by any chance?

Comment: These two machines have been defined in the Hosts

Comment: That did not really answer my question - it was about the contents of the hostname and/or visible name contents in the host properties.